# Sails.js + node-apn. Wrong encoding of notifications

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, apple-push-notifications, sails.js

I have annoying trouble with my node js server. I use sails.js framework (based on express) and use node-apn module (Apple Push Notification Service) for notifications. 
And all my notifications are shown in wrong encoding. If I send message in english everything is OK, but in another way I always see f*cking hierogliphics (need russian language). 
I'm a new in node js and I have no idea how to resolve my trouble. =(

**RESOLVE**

Just change document encoding to UTF-8.

Ref to node-apn: https://github.com/argon/node-apn

Comment: Can you give more details about how you're using processing the messages and calling node-apn

Comment: As I said problem doesn't exist any more. But If you want more details please visit http://dumpz.org/1500884/ (this is how I calling node-apn). And I work in team and I work only on server side so I don't know way of processing the messages.